What is a thread-safe way to pass commands to QThread, having QThread doing works according to the command, using Queue
I'm writing a microscope control program using PyQt5 and anaconda3. I use spyder from anaconda3. The program has to do a few things in parallel, for example, acquiring data, processing data , display data, etc... So, I decided to do multithreading. For communication between threads, I use queue.Queue().
I write a few QThread subclasses for different tasks, such as one below:
class AODOThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.AOtask = None
        self.DOtask = None
    
    def run(self):
        self.Init_Stages()
        self.StagebackQueue.get()
        self.QueueOut()
        
    def QueueOut(self):
        self.item = self.queue.get()
        while self.item.action != 'exit':
            try:
                if self.item.action == 'Xmove2':
                    self.Move(axis = 'X')
                elif self.item.action == 'Ymove2':
                    self.Move(axis = 'Y')
                elif self.item.action == 'Zmove2':
                    self.Move(axis = 'Z')
                elif self.item.action == 'XUP':
                    self.StepMove(axis = 'X', Direction = 'UP')
                elif self.item.action == 'YUP':
                    self.StepMove(axis = 'Y', Direction = 'UP')
                elif self.item.action == 'ZUP':
                    self.StepMove(axis = 'Z', Direction = 'UP')
                elif self.item.action == 'XDOWN':
                    self.StepMove(axis = 'X', Direction = 'DOWN')
                elif self.item.action == 'YDOWN':
                    self.StepMove(axis = 'Y', Direction = 'DOWN')
                elif self.item.action == 'ZDOWN':
                    self.StepMove(axis = 'Z', Direction = 'DOWN')
             except:
               # handle exceptions
             self.item = self.queue.get()

As you can see, I overwrite the run() function to make it do some initial work, then run the QueueOut(), which is basically waiting for commands from other threads, and once it get one command, it will do the corresponding work, such as move(), stepMove(), etc. Until it gets the 'exit' command, it will finish the QueueOut() function and this thread will finish. The command is received by dequeue the self.queue object, basically, the self.queue is my event slot for this subclass of QThread.
I have a few of such classes running, apart from the mainThread for the GUI. One of the threads is called 'weaverThread', it receives simple command from mainThread, such as 'acquire an image', then weaverThread passes multiple commands to other threads, such as 'move stage to this position' to the stage thread, 'acquire how many data in the digitizer' to the digitizer thread, 'process the data in GPU' to the GPU thread, 'display image on GUI' to the display thread. Some of this tasks have to run in parallel, some of them don't, but for the 'good looking of the code organization in my opinion', I put all of them into separate threads. And weaverThread organizes these threads like a thread weaver.
I also have a global variable called 'Memory', which is preallocated memory location for storing data acquired by digitizer. I made it global so that other threads can access the same memory location as well, such as the GPU thread which has to do data processing on the newly acquired data from digitizer. The way I initiate all threads are as bellow:
import sys
import numpy as np
from queue import Queue
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as QW
import PyQt5.QtCore as qc
from mainWindow import MainWindow
from Actions import *
from Generaic_functions import LOG
import time
# init global memory for temporary storage of generated raw data
global memoryCount
memoryCount = 3

global Memory
Memory = list(range(memoryCount))

global Digitizer

Digitizer = 'ART8912'

# init all Queues as global variable
# for any queue, you can do queue-in at multiple places, but you can only do queue-out at one place
global AODOQueue # AODO stands for analog output and digital output
global StagebackQueue # stage finish moving report queue
global WeaverQueue # King of all threads, gives command to other threads
global DnSQueue # DnS stands for display and save
global PauseQueue 
global GPUQueue 
global DQueue # D stands for digitizer
global DbackQueue # Dback stands for digitizer respond back, digitizer respond back if data collection is done
global StopDQueue # StopD stands for stop digitizer, for stopping digitizer in continuous acquisition
global GPU2weaverQueue

AODOQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
StagebackQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
WeaverQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
DnSQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
PauseQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
GPUQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
DQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
DbackQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
StopDQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
GPU2weaverQueue = Queue(maxsize = 0)
     
# wrap digitzer thread with queues and Memory
if Digitizer == 'ATS9351':
    # ATS9351 outputs 16bit data range
    AMPLIFICATION = 1*5
    from ThreadATS9351 import ATS9351
    class Digitizer_2(ATS9351):
        def __init__(self, ui, log):
            super().__init__()
            global Memory
            self.memoryCount = memoryCount
            self.Memory = Memory
            self.ui = ui
            self.queue = DQueue
            self.DbackQueue = DbackQueue
            self.StopDQueue = StopDQueue
            self.log = log
    
    from ThreadWeaver_ATS import WeaverThread
    class WeaverThread_2(WeaverThread):
        def __init__(self, ui, log):
            super().__init__()
            global Memory
            self.Memory = Memory
            self.memoryCount = memoryCount
            self.ui = ui
            self.queue = WeaverQueue
            self.DnSQueue = DnSQueue
            self.AODOQueue = AODOQueue
            self.StagebackQueue = StagebackQueue
            self.PauseQueue = PauseQueue
            self.StopDQueue = StopDQueue
            self.DbackQueue = DbackQueue
            self.GPUQueue = GPUQueue
            self.DQueue = DQueue
            self.GPU2weaverQueue = GPU2weaverQueue
            self.log = log
            
            
elif Digitizer == 'ART8912':
    # ART8912 outputs 12bit data range
    AMPLIFICATION = 16*5
    from ThreadART8912 import ART8912
    class Digitizer_2(ART8912):
        def __init__(self, ui, log):
            super().__init__()
            global Memory
            self.memoryCount = memoryCount
            self.Memory = Memory
            self.ui = ui
            self.queue = DQueue
            self.DbackQueue = DbackQueue
            self.StopDQueue = StopDQueue
            self.log = log

    # since ART8912 is master, AODO is slave,we need a separate weaver thread to organize them
    from ThreadWeaver_ART import WeaverThread
    class WeaverThread_2(WeaverThread):
        def __init__(self, ui, log):
            super().__init__()
            global Memory
            self.Memory = Memory
            self.memoryCount = memoryCount
            self.ui = ui
            self.queue = WeaverQueue
            self.DnSQueue = DnSQueue
            self.AODOQueue = AODOQueue
            self.StagebackQueue = StagebackQueue
            self.PauseQueue = PauseQueue
            self.StopDQueue = StopDQueue
            self.DbackQueue = DbackQueue
            self.GPUQueue = GPUQueue
            self.DQueue = DQueue
            self.GPU2weaverQueue = GPU2weaverQueue
            self.log = log

# wrap GPU thread with Queues and Memory
from ThreadGPU import GPUThread
class GPUThread_2(GPUThread):
    def __init__(self, ui, log):
            super().__init__()
            global Memory
            self.Memory = Memory
            self.ui = ui
            self.queue = GPUQueue
            self.DnSQueue = DnSQueue
            self.Digitizer = Digitizer
            self.GPU2weaverQueue = GPU2weaverQueue
            self.log = log
            self.AMPLIFICATION = AMPLIFICATION
# wrap AODO thread with queue
from ThreadAODO import AODOThread
class AODOThread_2(AODOThread):
    def __init__(self, ui, log):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = ui
        self.queue = AODOQueue
        self.Digitizer = Digitizer
        self.StagebackQueue = StagebackQueue
        self.log = log

# wrap Display and save thread with queue        
from ThreadDnS import DnSThread
class DnSThread_2(DnSThread):
    def __init__(self, ui, log):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = ui
        self.queue = DnSQueue
        self.Digitizer = Digitizer
        self.log = log
        
# wrap MainWindow object with queues and threads   
     
class GUI(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.log = LOG(self.ui)
        self.ui.RunButton.clicked.connect(self.run_task)
        self.ui.PauseButton.clicked.connect(self.Pause_task)
        
        self.ui.CenterGalvo.clicked.connect(self.CenterGalvo)
        
        # change window length for FFT
        self.ui.PostSamples.valueChanged.connect(self.update_Dispersion)
        self.ui.PreSamples.valueChanged.connect(self.update_Dispersion)
        self.ui.PostSamples_2.valueChanged.connect(self.update_Dispersion)
        self.ui.DelaySamples.valueChanged.connect(self.update_Dispersion)
        self.ui.TrimSamples.valueChanged.connect(self.update_Dispersion)
        
        self.ui.XYmax.valueChanged.connect(self.Update_contrast_XY)
        self.ui.XYmin.valueChanged.connect(self.Update_contrast_XY)
        self.ui.XYZmax.valueChanged.connect(self.Update_contrast_XYZ)
        self.ui.XYZmin.valueChanged.connect(self.Update_contrast_XYZ)
        self.ui.Surfmax.valueChanged.connect(self.Update_contrast_Surf)
        self.ui.Surfmin.valueChanged.connect(self.Update_contrast_Surf)
        
        self.ui.RedoDC.clicked.connect(self.redo_dispersion_compensation)
        self.ui.redoBG.clicked.connect(self.redo_background)
        self.ui.BG_DIR.textChanged.connect(self.update_background)
        self.ui.Disp_DIR.textChanged.connect(self.update_Dispersion)
        self.ui.Xmove2.clicked.connect(self.Xmove2)
        self.ui.Ymove2.clicked.connect(self.Ymove2)
        self.ui.Zmove2.clicked.connect(self.Zmove2)
        self.ui.XUP.clicked.connect(self.XUP)
        self.ui.YUP.clicked.connect(self.YUP)
        self.ui.ZUP.clicked.connect(self.ZUP)
        self.ui.XDOWN.clicked.connect(self.XDOWN)
        self.ui.YDOWN.clicked.connect(self.YDOWN)
        self.ui.ZDOWN.clicked.connect(self.ZDOWN)
        self.ui.InitStageButton.clicked.connect(self.InitStages)
        self.ui.StageUninit.clicked.connect(self.Uninit)
        self.ui.ZstageTest.clicked.connect(self.ZstageTest)
        self.ui.ZstageTest2.clicked.connect(self.ZstageTest2)
        self.ui.SliceDir.clicked.connect(self.SliceDirection)
        self.ui.VibEnabled.clicked.connect(self.Vibratome)
        self.ui.SliceN.valueChanged.connect(self.change_slice_number)
        # self.ui.Gotozero.stateChanged.connect(self.Gotozero)
        self.Init_allThreads()
        
    def Init_allThreads(self):
        self.Weaver_thread = WeaverThread_2(self.ui, self.log)
        self.AODO_thread = AODOThread_2(self.ui, self.log)
        self.DnS_thread = DnSThread_2(self.ui, self.log)
        self.GPU_thread = GPUThread_2(self.ui, self.log)
        self.D_thread = Digitizer_2(self.ui, self.log)
        
        self.D_thread.start()
        self.GPU_thread.start()
        self.Weaver_thread.start()
        self.AODO_thread.start()
        self.DnS_thread.start()
            
    def Stop_allThreads(self):
        exit_element=EXIT()
        WeaverQueue.put(exit_element)
        AODOQueue.put(exit_element)
        DnSQueue.put(exit_element)
        GPUQueue.put(exit_element)
        DQueue.put(exit_element)
        

Note that I also pass the self.ui variable to all subthreads, so that they can read the user input directly. Magically, even though I did not make self.ui global, the changes made in one thread can be read by another thread as well, for example, in weaverThread I change '# pixels in X dimension' to be 100, then as the the AODO_thread is going to read '# pixels in X dimension' , it got 100 instead of the original value! This is confusing to me, but not really related to my real issue here.
Now my question is, is this a thread-safe way to organize multiple threads to do works in parallel? Because I got program crash very often, the traceback is:
Windows fatal exception: code 0xc0000374


Thread 0x00000eec (most recent call first):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\queue.py", line 171 in get
  File "D:\SSOCT_HE\software\

Thread 0x00002dc8 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\nidaqmx\_library_interpreter.py", line 5542 in wait_until_task_done
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\nidaqmx\task.py", line 926 in wait_until_done
  File "D:\SSOCT_HE\software\

Thread 0x00003124 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\queue.py", line 171 in get
  File "D:\SSOCT_HE\software\

Thread 0x00000ce0 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\queue.py", line 171 in get
  File "D:\SSOCT_HE\software\

Thread 0x00003ee4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\queue.py", line 171 in get
  File "D:\SSOCT_HE\software\

Main thread:
Thread 0x000038c8 (most recent call first):
  File "d:\ssoct_he\software\ssoct_mt.py", line 456 in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356 in compat_exec
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 473 in exec_code
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 615 in _exec_file
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 528 in runfile
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1840\1107618726.py", line 1 in <module>


Restarting kernel...

The crash has happened in three situations:

when digitizer start to acquire data, sometimes it crashes before data is fully acquired, sometimes it crashes after data is fully acquired. I know this because I made digitizer to print 'start acquiring' and 'finished acquiring' at the beginning and end of acquisition. immediately after data acquisition, the stage is going to move elsewhere, so I'm not sure if it's due to digitizer or stage thread. This accounts for about 99% of the time when it crashes.
when Z stage is about to move. This only happened once, before it crashed, the program has moved X and Y stages successfully.
when display thread is updating the image on GUI and I kept change the brightness and contrast of the displayed image. How it works is that, in each image update, the GPU thread will send a command (i.e., enqueue to the display queue) to display thread. And similarly, each brightness adjustment, the mainThread will enqueue to the display queue a command. So in this situation, the display queue is receiving tons of commands from both GPU and GUI. After about 5 seconds of continuous display and brightness adjust, the program crashed.

I don't think this is a hardware problem, since all of works from all threads needs to be done multiple times, and the crash doesn't happen at initial run of any specific work, rather, it happens almost randomly.
I don't think there is a racing issue, even with the global Memory, i.e., each variable is only read or write once at the same time.
The code 0xc0000374 means heap corruption, I don't know what caused that, all I can think of now is maybe my thread and queue management is not 'safe'?

update anaconda3, but failed to update spyder due to no access to C:/.../anaconda3. Problem still exists
block access to Memory in all queues other than digitizer, so Memory is only accessed by digitizer, problem still exists
replacing some hardware thread by simulation, problem still exists

